# using multiple Viewpager ,How to set View pager match_parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

> I am Using two Viewpagers and I got an error when I run the project, the second Viewpager doesn't show but when I set the height value(Eg:312dp) then it will show, I want to show that viewpager with height match_parent. what I have to do please help me
>
> main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp">
                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pagerDemo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#2c3e50"
                      />
                    </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>



                      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                          android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:background="#251233"/>
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:background="#4492a7"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

main.class

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPager mviewPager;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//
//      toolbar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        mviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerDemo);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new pageradapter(this);
        mviewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "Top Tracks");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "Fasion");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "Wheels");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "Clurnery");
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "Education");
        adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "Technology");
        adapter.addFrag(new SevenFragment(), "REGGAE");
        adapter.addFrag(new EightFragment(), "PROCRESSIVE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }


        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

adapter.class

public class pageradapter extends PagerAdapter

    {
        private int[] image_resouce = {R.drawable.thired, R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.phone};
        Context context;
        public pageradapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }


        @Override
        public int getCount () {
        return image_resouce.length;
    }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject (View view, Object object){
        return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
    }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container,int position){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pageview, container, false);

        ImageView im = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imPager);

        im.setImageResource(image_resouce[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container,int position, Object object){
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this WrappedViewPager class instead of ViewPager and set height wrap_content for WrappedViewPager.

```
public class WrappedViewPager extends ViewPager {

public WrappedViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public WrappedViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
} }
```

Replace with your viewpager in your laout:

```
<your_package_name_where_you_put_this_class.WrappedViewPager
                      android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you applied WrappedViewPager in your XML file properly for both viewpager

Comment: <your_package_name_where_you_put_this_class. WrappedViewPager
                          android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml, you need to change tablayout above viewpager. 
You need to set the height to match_parent, as there property are cascaded from top bottom.

Comment: actually i need this design

Comment: you have already pasted the design, just need the modification.